# 504 gateway timeout django site with nginx+fastcgi

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

we added ability for admin users to change server date&time through the portal. Changing the date&time back is working fine, but changing forward(more than fastcgi_read_timeout) is returning '504 gateway timeout' even though server time successfully changed behind the scenes.

Please advice how to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you changing the date/time? Altering the timezone in Django, the timezone in the OS or the actual date/time in the operation system? Changing the actual time on a server can have serious undesired consequences and should not be 'normal' procedure. Use NTP to keep the system in step.

Comment: Actual date/time of OS(Ubuntu 12.04). We are also giving ability to change timezone and ntp servers from same portal. I agree with you about not to mess with OS time but requirement came in like that and I can't argue. I guess some customers don't want to connect server to internet or setup NTP.

Comment: My suggestion would be to try restarting/reloading services until it works or as a last resort a server reboot. You can then add those steps to the process. I'd personally recommend a reboot to make sure that key daemons like cron, MTAs, syslog providers etc are all in a good state.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll try to restart those services. But is there a way to send back success response without time-out error?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with another project. Maybe it is best to submit the date&time credentials (I assume you would be using NTP servers IPs to do this) through the portal asynchronously via a JavaScript AJAX request. Then, let the server then do its thing with the date&time.

Meanwhile, have the client side JavaScript, continuously probe the server with interval AJAX requests (perhaps every 5 seconds) to get back a response message on the server time. That way, each subsequent AJAX request initiates a new Nginx session and if the first fails/timeouts, then try a second time, if that fails, then try a third time, and so on.

This worked on our system. However, I do not know if your product has login/authentication credentials. If it does, then the user may have to log back in once all set and done because a change in time may also expire their log-in session. I don't think this is such a big deal though because theoretically they should only need to change the date/time once in a while if not just one time only. So it shouldn't have too much of an impact on the user experience.

tags: nginx, NTP, timeout, 504